# Polylang pll_e() screws up text positioning - what's wrong with my syntax?

Tags: php, woocommerce, syntax, translation, polylang

reading this question ([Polylang: How to translate custom strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46557981/polylang-how-to-translate-custom-strings)) I managed to create a custom string that is registered and translatable with Polylang, but when I add the pll_e() to my code snippet, the text is not placed correctly on frontend:

Using this code snippet, the "on backorder" text is translatable but is placed BEFORE the item name, instead of after the name:

```
$item_name .='<br /><div class="backorder">' .$backorder_qty. pll_e('on backorder').'</div>';
```

When I remove the pll_e(), the text displays correctly AFTER the item name, as it should:

```
$item_name .='<br /><div class="backorder">' .$backorder_qty." on backorder".'</div>';
```

Can you see what I do wrong when adding the pll_e() in the first line of code? Attached image shows how the text is misplaced. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: `pll_e` echos, `pll__` returns. Use the latter when you are concatenating.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thank you very much.